# Implement authorization for ActiveRecord methods

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, authorization

I've been trying to implement an authorization layer on top of ActiveRecord. Let me explain how that is supposed to work.

### Databases

Consider a database table `Invoices` with the following fields

- InvoiceId
- CustomerId
- ... other fields

There will be an auxiliary table `InvoicePrivileges` with the fields

- ObjectId (referring to an invoice id)
- SubjectId (referring to a customer id in this case)
- Subject type (to handle multiple kinds of users - customer, admin, operator, etc)
- Read (boolean)
- Write (boolean)

### Authorization checks

To be able to read an invoice, the entity attempting to `read` the row or set of rows must have a set of entries in the `InvoicePrivileges` table (where `InvoicePrivileges.object_id` refers to an `InvoiceId`) with `InvoicePrivileges.read = true`.

Example, a query to fetch a bunch of invoices from the DB

```
SELECT invoice.*
FROM Invoices invoice
LEFT JOIN InvoicePrivileges privilege 
    ON invoice.invoice_id = privilege.object_id
    AND privilege.subject_id = <user_id>
    AND privilege.subject_type = <user_type>
WHERE privilege.read = TRUE;
```

The same condition applies when trying to `update` an invoice, except the last `WHERE` condition becomes `WHERE privilege.write = true`.

### Implementation

I can use the [Arel library](https://github.com/rails/arel) to create these constraints with ease. However, where do I implement these methods in such a way that all ActiveRecord save and update actions include these constraints?

I don't mind writing a bit of code to enable this. I'm looking for pointers as to how best to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a gem and require it after ActiveRecord gem. In your gem open up ActiveRecord classes and override the interested methods.

```
module ActiveRecord
  class Base

    def save(*)
      if(authorised?)
        super
      else
        raise NotAuthorisedError.new("Your meaningful message!")
      end
    end

  end
end
```

The original code from Rails source is in [Persistence class](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L124). All persistence methods usually use `create_or_update` method internally. So, you might consider overriding that method instead. But, you need to look through the code and see if that's a good idea.

Comment: As helpful as this is, I'm looking more for the `if that's a good idea` part